# Do ros2 have available four_wheel_steering controller?

Tags: microcontroller, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
Sorry for all mistakes, English is not my native language.
So, I have four wheeled robot on ROS Noetic and I trying to port it on ROS2 Galactic. One of my main problems right now is I can't find four_wheel controller for my robot, and migrating of my old controller wasn't very successful. Coul'd you help me? All that I found is this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fR47Y7p4mtQ where you can find link on the currently existing controllers, but four_wheel_steering controller is not one of them and won't be for I don't know how long.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407177/do-ros2-have-available-four_wheel_steering-controller?/) by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2022-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's the list of available controllers, at least the officially maintained ones:   https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers

It looks like the closest right now is the tricycle controller. Possibly you could make that work for your application.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2022-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edvard](https://answers.ros.org/users/119522/edvard/) on 2022-10-06**:
I'll check it. Thanks